# VBA Access: Import CSV with additonal header data

Tags: vba, ms-access, csv

I am new to coding VBA. Was wondering if you all could help me? I have a CSV file which is structured as the following:
- First 22 rows cover the specfic header data(this all loads in one column in excel)
- column headers for table are in Row 23
- the data is actually located from row 24 onward.

What the code needs to do is insert this data in new table with the right column titles. Also while inserting it needs to input the file name and header data in the first few columns of the table.

So far I have imported the entire CSV into an array I believe:

See what I have so far:

```
Sub readCSV()
Dim fs As Object
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim tsIn As Object
Dim sFileIn, filename As String
Dim aryFile, aryHeader, aryBody As Variant

sFileIn = "C:\doc\test.csv"

Set filename = fso.GetFileName(sFileIn)

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tsIn = fs.OpenTextFile(sFileIn, 1)
sTmp = tsIn.ReadAll
aryFile = Split(sTmp, vbCrLf)

For i = 1 To 22
    aryHeader(1, i) = aryFile(i)
Next i

For i = 23 To UBound(aryFile)
    aryBody(i) = Split(aryFile(i), ",")
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MAINS VALUES (filename,aryHeader(1),aryBody(i))"
Next i

End Sub
```

is this correct? Can anyone see of i am taking the right approach

UPDATE - recoded this a bit

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help or make suggest where to start?

Comment: Can someone check this code... updating in the original post...

Comment: Hmm, not that you are doing it wrong, but I think you are writing a lot more code and executing a lot more SQL than you need to.  Take a look at DoCmd.TransferText.  You can bring in the whole file with one line of code, maybe into a staging (temp) table, then play with it from there using queries and/or DAO.  Also brush up on string concatenation in VBA because your RunSQL command, everything else aside, will not do what you expect.  Would look something more like: "INSERT INTO MAINS VALUES ('" &  filename & "', '" &aryHeader(1) & "', '" & aryBody(i) &')".  Good luck.

Comment: Hi VBlade, Thanks for the inputs, I was originally using DoCmd.TransferText however this was failing because of how the csv file is structured. When i was deleting the header data (first 22 rows) it worked fine... but i need the header data, which seems to break the DoCmd.TransferText. Hence i am trying to customise the import program. Completely forgot about the  concatenation. Thanks

Comment: Ok, fair enough, that make sense.  Otherwise, they way you are doing things should work.  Debug.Print can help you out to see if you are getting the values you expect (will output to Debug window - Ctrl+G).  I would probably just go through and make sure you are getting what you expect from the variables before putting the dynamic SQL together.  Sometimes you think there is a problem with code when it is your SQL string.  Maybe even Debug.Print the whole SQL string out and run a line in a query just to make sure everything is kosher.  But yeah, I think you will be fine the way you're doing it.

Comment: Also, why is aryHeader 2-dimensional?  Not sure what you are trying to do.  In any case, you never refer to a second dimension in your SQL string for aryHeader, so pretty sure that is an issue.  And when you are splitting aryFile into aryBody and trying to use it in your SQL, you will need to refer to the limit of aryBody (which is the number of fields in each row), not i.  Split will take a string and stuff it into an array of n elements, determined by the occurrences of the delimiter.  You don't want to be referring to the row number there (i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i ended up:

```
Sub ReadCSV2()
Dim fs As Object
Dim filename As String
Dim tsIn As Object
Dim sFileIn As String
Dim aryHeader, aryBody As Variant
Dim Text As String
Dim sqlcre As String
Dim sqlsta As String

sFileIn =   "C:\test\test.csv"
filename = GetFilenameFromPath(sFileIn) 'function to get the file name
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tsIn = fs.OpenTextFile(sFileIn, 1)

For i = 1 To 23
    Tmps = tsIn.ReadLine
Next i

aryHeader = Split(Tmps, ",")

On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.RunSQL "DROP TABLE tempdata"
On Error GoTo 0

sqlcre = "CREATE TABLE tempdata ([Filename] Text,"
For k = LBound(aryHeader) To UBound(aryHeader)
    sqlcre = sqlcre & "[" & aryHeader(k) & " " & k + 1 & "] Text,"
Next k
k = k - 1
sqlcre = Left(sqlcre, Len(sqlcre) - 13) & ")"
'Debug.Print k
'Debug.Print sqlcre
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlcre
DoCmd.SetWarnings False         
While Not tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Tmps = tsIn.ReadLine
     aryBody = Split(Tmps, ",")
     sqlsta = "INSERT INTO tempdata VALUES ('" & filename & "','"
     For M = LBound(aryBody) To UBound(aryBody)
         sqlsta = sqlsta & Replace(aryBody(M), "'", "`") & "', '"
     Next M
     M = M - 1
     Debug.Print M
     If M < k Then
         Text = ""
         For i = 1 To (k - M)
             Text = Text & "', '"
         Next i
         sqlsta = sqlsta & Text
     End If
    sqlsta = Left(sqlsta, Len(sqlsta) - 7) & ")"
     'Debug.Print sqlsta
     'Debug.Print k
     DoCmd.RunSQL sqlsta

Wend
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks scary, but glad you figured it out! =)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DoCmd.TransferText` instead of rolling out your own code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958%28v=office.15%29.aspx

In your Import Specification, you can set the starting row.

See [Skip first three lines of CSV file (using DoCmd?) in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300980/skip-first-three-lines-of-csv-file-using-docmd-in-ms-access) for more information!

**Edit:** The import specification can be changed to rename the fields etc. See http://www.access-programmers.com/creating-an-import-specification-in-access-2003.aspx (the Import wizard exists in Access 2007 as well) and the *Advanced* dialog specifically.

Comment: Hi MP24, Thanks, I actually was going to take this approach, however the default DoCmd.TransferText function will import the the column headers as they are in the CSV file. Only issue with this is some of the column headers have exactly the same name.. so would need to be renamed. this is one of the reasons why i went down the custom import path.

Comment: See my edit: you can rename fields in the import wizard

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit irked by the use of multiple arrays in your code (which is super confusing, to me, anyway, because you are looking at counters everywhere) so I thought I would post an alternative for you.  If you can do it your way, more power to you, but if you run into problems, you can try this.  Code below is much more verbose, but may save you time in the future if you hand it off or even have to come back to it yourself and have no idea what is going on (lol):

```
Sub ReadCSV()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler    

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim tst As Scripting.TextStream

    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim intCurrentLine As Integer

    Dim strCurrentLine As String
    Dim intHeaderRows As Integer
    Dim strHeader As String
    Dim strHeaderDelimInField As String

    'Consider these your 'constants', so you don't come back to this code in a month
    'and wonder what the random numbers mean.
    intHeaderRows = 22              'Number of header rows in CSV.
    strHeaderDelimInField = "~"     'The character(s) you want to separate each
                                    'header line, in field.

    strFileName = "C:\IrregularCSV.csv"
    intCurrentLine = 1      'Keep track of which line in the file we are currently on.

    'Next two lines get a reference to your table; will add data via DAO and not SQL,
    'to avoid messy dynamic SQL.
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Mains", dbOpenDynaset)

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set tst = fso.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)

    'Instead of storing data in arrays, let's go through the file line by line
    'and do the work we need to do.
    With tst
        Do Until .AtEndOfStream
            strCurrentLine = .ReadLine

            If intCurrentLine <= intHeaderRows Then
                strHeader = strHeader & strHeaderDelimInField & strCurrentLine
            Else
                'Add the records via DAO here.
                rst.AddNew
                    'In DAO, rst.Fields("FieldName") are the columns in your table.
                    rst.Fields("FileName") = strFileName

                    'Remove leading delimiter with Right.
                    rst.Fields("HeaderInfo") = Right(strHeader, Len(strHeader) - 1) 

                    'Note that Split always returns a zero-based array
                    'and is unaffected by the Option Base statement.
                    'The way below is less efficient than storing
                    'the return of Split, but also less confusing, imo.
                    rst.Fields("Field1") = Split(strCurrentLine, ",")(0)
                    rst.Fields("Field2") = Split(strCurrentLine, ",")(1)
                    rst.Fields("Field3") = Split(strCurrentLine, ",")(2)
                rst.Update
            End If

            intCurrentLine = intCurrentLine + 1
        Loop
    End With

    tst.Close
    rst.Close

ExitMe:
    Set tst = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    GoTo ExitMe

End Sub
```

To be honest, I think there are a lot of gotchas to the way you are going about it.  Not saying it won't work, because I think it can, but this method is more robust.  An unexpected single quote won't ruin your work and using a data object to do the inserts is not prone (well, less, at least) to SQL injection issues.  And I've done it with no persisted arrays.  Anyway, some food for thought.  Good luck.

Comment: Hey VBlades, Thanks i will take a look at this and see if i can get this to work...in the mean time i changed my current code( see update in original post) which seems to work except for the annoying append row pop which seems to continually pop up at the end of each row being inserted.

Comment: this way may be quicker actually.. having performance issue with my code. It takes a while to input in the table due the the large number of records

Comment: Hi Vblades, How do you check if a table exists in vba access?

Comment: The proper way to do it is (not in front of Access, so syntax):

Public Function DoesTableExist(strTableName) As Boolean

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

DoesTableExist = False

Set db = CurrentDB()

For Each tdf in db.TableDefs
    If tdf.Name = strTableName Then
        DoesTableExist = True
        Exit For
    End If 
Next 

Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Function

Comment: Hi VBlades, Do you know how to zip and encrypt a directory from vba?

Comment: @NewCoderNat: Hi Nat.  I'm a bit busy nowadays, it would probably best if you post new question and let the community figure it out. :)