# MS Access VBA import csv into new table by using SQL and Schema.ini - Force column names of table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013, import-csv

In a folder `C:\Excel`, I have these files:

- test.csv
- Schema.ini

`Schema.ini` contains:

```
[test.csv] 
Format=Delimited(;)
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=2
CharacterSet=ANSI
DecimalSymbol=, 

Col1=Lot Char
Col2=dateResa1 Date
Col3=PRIXLOG_IMMO Double
Col4=MONTANT_CA_ESTIME Double
```

And in MS Access, I have an export routine which loads csv file data into a created table : TEST

```
Private Sub importCSV_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

On Error Resume Next: DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "TEST": On Error GoTo 0

strSQL = " SELECT CStr(t.lot), CDate(t.dateResa1), CDbl(t.PRIXLOG_IMMO), CDbl(t.MONTANT_CA_ESTIME) " & _
" INTO TEST  " & _
" FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=ANSI;DATABASE=C:\Excel].[test.csv] t"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

End Sub
```

It works great but the column names of the table MS-Access TEST are named:

- Expr1001
- Expr1002...and so on

Is there a way to force the name of columns table TEST by using only SQL and `Schema.ini` ?

**Solution:**

Because I casted the fields with CStr, CDate..., field names must be redefined with an alias  and Icing on the cake, alias can be as same as field name. I tested it

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986775/vba-access-import-csv-with-additonal-header-data

Comment: Thanks aggaton but to tell the truth not at all  because the issue proposed is to complex and heavy

Comment: Because I casted the fields with CStr, CDate..., field names must be redifined with an alias  and Icing on the cake, alias can be as same as field name. I tested it

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding a cast of fields in Access SQL, the declaration of the type for each column in Schema.ini is enough and  allow to use * in Access query !